# Active tab link and content based on the href attribute is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have this method below to update the user password. After the user click in the button to update I want to redirect him to the same page and have the tab with id "editPassword" as active.

I have the code below for that but is not working properly, after the user click in the "update password" button is redirected to "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#editPassword" and the active tab link becomes the "#editPassword" but the tab content dont changes, the tab content remains the content of the default active tab.

Do you know where is the issue?

laravel:

```
public function updatePassword(Request $request){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'new_password' => 'required|string|min:6|',
            'new_password_confirm' => 'same:new_password',
        ]);

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->password = bcrypt($request->new_password);
        $user->save();
        Session::flash('success', 'PasswordUpdated.');

        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#editPassword');
    }
```

jquery:

```
 var path = window.location.href;

                $('.registration_form_list a').each(function () {
                    var hash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];

                    if (this.href === path) {

                        $('.registration_form_list a').removeClass('active');
                        $('a[href="#'+hash+'"]').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Should `this.href` be `$(this).attr("href")` in your check condition?

Comment: Thanks, but like that also dont work. The "alert(path);" shows "http://proj.test/user/profile?user=1#editPassword" the alert($(this).attr("href")) shows "#editPassword"